# RedirectToAction с параметром

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, controller

Допустим у нас есть `ActionMethod` с параметром `int`:

```
public ActionMethod Create(int? id)
{
    . . .
    return View();
}
```

И еще есть другой `ActionMethod` (в том же контроллере) в котором перенаправляемся к первому методу:

```
public ActionMethod Index()
{
    . . . .
    return RedirectToAction("Create");
}
```

Вопрос: как передать параметр (допустим id = 5) в `Create(int? id)`?

Comment: Прежде чем проголосовать против подумайте дважды, это "учебный материал" для русскоязычных пользователей.

Comment: так тут ведь достаточно справку по функции посмотреть: [RedirectToAction](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd460291(v=vs.118).aspx)

Comment: @Grundy Не очень то достаточно там объясняется как принимать значение в контроллере как параметр и еще для опытных программистов много чего может оказаться очевидным, но не для новичков, к которым и в основном направлен этот сайт.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно передать следующим образом:

```
public ActionMethod Index()
{
    . . . .
    return RedirectToAction("Create", new { id = 5 });
}
```

Это приведет к перенаправлению в `"Сайт"/"Контроллер"/Create/5.`

Comment: к какому перенаправлению это приведет зависит от настроек роута

Comment: Да, но тут речь идет о настроек по умолчанию, об этом можно открыть другую тему.

Comment: У меня перенаправляет на `/Caйт/Контроллер?id=5`